# Going from Page to Window with Timer on Gives a STA Problem?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have a problem where I run my program and it gives me a STA Error on my "Test" Window. It does not have an error if I don't have a timer going from the Page I am running till the window. I'll show and Example:

```
 public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            var page = new TestW();
            page.Show();
        }
        );

    }
```

This is from my Page1 to open up my TestW ( Test Window ) 
My main code looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Luk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Login
    {
        Main.Content = new Page1();
        Framep.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        GridS.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }
}
```

And my XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="date_app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:date_app"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="400"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStyle="None"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    >

<Border BorderBrush="Black"
         BorderThickness="1.5"  
         CornerRadius="10"
         >
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="ImageBrush" ImageSource="Images\bgapp.png" Stretch="None"/>
    </Border.Background>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Framep">
            <Frame x:Name="Main" />
        </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="GridS">

        <!--X Luk Knappen.-->
        <Grid>
            <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Name="Luk" Margin="360, 10, 10, 0" Background="Transparent" Click="Luk_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="Images\Ikke-navngivet.png" Height="20" Width="35" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Image Source="Images\DateL.png" Height="200"/>
        </Grid>
        <!--Username.-->
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource WatermarkTextbox}" Name="Email" Height="30" Width="300" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Text="Hello" Margin="0 40 0 0" TextChanged="Email_TextChanged"/>
        </Grid>

        <!--Password.-->
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource WatermarkTextbox1}" Name="Pass" Height="30" Width="300" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Text="Hello" Margin="0 35 0 0" TextChanged="Pass_TextChanged"/>
        </Grid>

        <!--Login Knap.-->
        <Grid>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Log ind" Width="80" Height="30" FontSize="20" Margin="0 100 0 0" Click="Button_Click" />
        </Grid>

        <!--Opret Bruger-->
        <Grid>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Opret Bruger" Width="140" Height="30" FontSize="20" Margin="0 20 0 0" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Page1 Code:

```
<Page x:Class="date_app.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:gif="https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:date_app"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="400"
  Title="LoadingM">
<Border BorderBrush="Black"
         BorderThickness="1.5"  
         CornerRadius="10"
         >
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="ImageBrush" ImageSource="Images\bgapp.png" Stretch="None"/>
    </Border.Background>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="LOADING. . ." FontSize="50" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
        <Image gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="Images\CatGif.gif"  />

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The problem I have: If I run with the Task Delay My test Window gets an STA Error that I don't know how to fix.

If I run without the Task Delay It just opens it all up but no STA Error.

I am trying to do this:

When I press on the Login button It is supposed to open the Page1 and hide the main window for a " Loading " Screen and then after the delay to close Main window + Page1 down to Open up the New Window.  Been sitting with this for a little while :) Thanks in advance!

-- Test Window Is plain. No code there.

[This is the Background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh9au.png)

Comment: The Task class has a learning curve, you haven't started climbing it yet.  Get ahead by using a DispatcherTimer instead.

Comment: I'm suspecting that your code in `ContinueWith` does get called on a ThreadPool-Thread. Could you add the error message?

Comment: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this. This is the message i get. But the message i get comes from the Test Window I have.

Comment: Please check on which thread the `ContinueWith` of the `Task.Delay()` is executed. If it is not excecuted on the UiThread then the error is that any UI components must be created and handled by an STA thread.

Comment: It is running in the Main Thread. I just got told.

Comment: The timer isn't the problem. You're trying to modify the UI from a background thread and that's simply not possible. Use `await Task.Delay();` instead of `ContinueWith()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `Action` given to `ContinueWith` will not be exectued on the UiThread but on a free ThreadPool-Thread, so the new `TestW` object will be constructed and used by a non STA-Thread. But any WPF-UI-component must be constructed and used by an STA-Thread.

The solution is to replace your `Task.Delay()` with

```
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var page = new TestW();
        page.Show();
    });
});
```

This will delegate your execution back to the UiThread.